# Fetching parent data using Child Data in OneToMany JPA Relationship in spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a classic problem where i need to find the parent data by using child data in One To Many JPA relationship

## Scenario

I need to find all the student who lives in one city(ex- Delhi) and locality ( ex- west delhi)

I have one class as Studen and Another class as Address , In address class we are having these attributes in Class

I also have StudentRepository , now what Query Method should i write in Repository where i can get all the Students on address Filters basis

I am using Spring boot and Spring data

Please help me

If you need i can share the code!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method in StudentRepository for the desired result
    `findByAddressCityAndAddressLocality(String city, String locality);`